# i have a check from a title company dated 8 years ago

Tags: title-insurance

i was cleaning up and throwing papers aways and in those paper i found a check dated 8 years ago. my question is if i can still claim the check , or do something about it so i can get a new one, i would appreciate all the help thank you...so i contacted the title company and after i told them the amount they told me they did a wire transfer 12 days after i recieve the check.is that normal?

Comment: Have you considered asking the title company for details about the wire transfer? To _which account_ was the money sent by wire transfer, and what was the amount sent (they might have deducted wire transfer fees)? If they name _your_ account, then it is up to you to prove that the money never arrived in your account. If you are in the habit of throwing away all bank records more than 4 years old, you may have to go to your bank and get them to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Banks are not required to honor a check past about six months, so that check is pretty useless except as additional evidence that they did intend to pay you this amount at that time. (Though presumably you kept other papers which provide the same evidence.)

As Dilip said, you need get the amount, date, and account number the wire transfer was sent to, then check that against your bank to see if it reached you. If it did, you've been paid what you were owed, end of discussion. If somehow it got misdirected, you and they will have to work with your banks to figure out how this can be corrected.